# COUNT and SELECT into the same query in mySQL

Tags: mysql

Form my two tables, I want to select `SUB_Limit` and count the number of rooms (**only the active one**).

So the query should returns me something like this:

```
|-----------|------------|-------------|
| SUB_Limit | ROO_Number | ROO_HotelId |
|-----------|------------|-------------|
|        10 |          0 |           1 |
|        15 |          3 |           2 |
|         5 |          2 |           3 |
|        25 |          0 |           4 |
|-----------|------------|-------------|
```

Why this query do not return me the desired output please ?

```
SELECT 
    ROO_HotelId, 
    SUB_Limit, 
    COUNT(ROO_Id) AS ROO_Number
FROM ___Rooms
LEFT JOIN ___Subscriptions
    ON ___Rooms.ROO_HotelId = ___Subscriptions.SUB_HotelId
WHERE ROO_Status = 'active'
    AND SUB_HotelId = 1
    AND ROO_HotelId = 1
```

Actually, it gave me:

```
|-----------|------------|
| SUB_Limit | ROO_Number |
|-----------|------------|
|        15 |          3 |
|         5 |          2 |
|-----------|------------|
```

So I haven't the `___Subscriptions` with no rooms.

Here the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6920c/1) for help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is basically because there's nothing in the Rooms table with hotelID 1

Comment: @JavierLarroulet, yes it the case here. But how I can handle this? Thanks.

Comment: you could do `Subscriptions LEFT JOIN Rooms` (not the same as `Rooms RIGHT JOIN Subscriptions`) and handle the case when the rightmost side of the join returns null via code. That's how I'd do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query below gives you the result you want.

```
SELECT 
  SUB_HotelId,
  SUB_Limit, 
  COUNT(ROO_Id) AS ROO_Number  
FROM ___Subscriptions
LEFT JOIN ___Rooms ON 
  ___Rooms.ROO_HotelId = ___Subscriptions.SUB_HotelId
WHERE ROO_Status = 'active' or ROO_Status is null
GROUP BY SUB_HotelId
```

You need to check for ROO_Status = 'active' or NULL because if the subscription is not linked to a room, there will be no value for ROO_Status. Also, you need to group on SUB_HotelId, because ROO_HotelId will also be null if there is no room to join the subscription to.

Link to fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6920c/35